# How to remove rogue arrowhead in TikZ drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-matrix

This is my first time using TikZ, I looked at a lot of examples and managed to piece together exactly what I wanted. However, there is a rogue arrowhead in the diagram that I just cannot seem to get rid of. Even if I remove the last set of boxes, the rogue arrowhead remains. I'm sure it is a very simple fix but I have no clue what to change. I should mention, before using the code `\draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}]` and `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` everything was fine, just that the arrowheads were very small.

Below is the sample code and resulting image, thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    every matrix/.style={
        inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        matrix of math nodes,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            draw=black,
            font=\color{black},
            minimum size=.75cm,
            anchor=center
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{root} = [circle,draw=black, thick]

\node[root] (root) at (0,2){root};
\matrix (l0) at (0,0) {a & ... & z\\};

\matrix (l10) at (-2,-2) {a & ... & z\\};
\matrix (l11) at (1,-2) {a & ... & z\\};
\matrix (l12) at (4,-2) {a & ... & z\\};

\matrix (l20) at (-3,-4) {a & ... & z\\};
\matrix (l21) at (0,-4) {a & ... & z\\};
\matrix (l22) at (3,-4) {a & ... & z\\};
\matrix (l23) at (6,-4) {a & ... & z\\};

  \draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}]
    (root.south) edge (l0-1-2.north)
    (l0-1-1.south) edge (l10-1-2.north)
    (l0-1-2.south) edge (l11-1-2.north)
    (l0-1-3.south) edge (l12-1-2.north)

    (l10-1-2.south) edge (l20-1-2.north)
    (l10-1-3.south) edge (l21-1-2.north)
    (l11-1-2.south) edge (l22-1-2.north)
    (l12-1-2.south) edge (l23-1-2.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can too add these option `\begin{tikzpicture}[tips=on proper draw]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `\draw` with `\path`, because that's what is creating an arrowhead... without a path, and the various `edge` commands are also creating paths with arrowheads, so the final result is a series of correct paths, plus an extra arrowhead.

Basically it's like this in your code:

```
\draw [-{Latex[length=3mm]}]% a path without coordinates... so just the head!
    (root.south) edge (l0-1-2.north) % oh another path
    (l0-1-1.south) edge (l10-1-2.north) % ...and another path
    (l0-1-2.south) edge (l11-1-2.north) % and so on...
    (l0-1-3.south) edge (l12-1-2.north)

    (l10-1-2.south) edge (l20-1-2.north)
    (l10-1-3.south) edge (l21-1-2.north)
    (l11-1-2.south) edge (l22-1-2.north)
    (l12-1-2.south) edge (l23-1-2.north);% and the head goes here
```

You could also remove `[-{Latex[length=3mm]}]` and place it next to every `edge`, but that isn't very good practice: too much typing, if you change one, you have to change 10 others, etc.

So using either solution the result is the following:

[image]